# Why does setVisible() remove my components?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So in the following code, putting frame.add(OpeningSplash) before SetVisible(true) works properly (that is, displays the image) but putting it after doesn't. How would I fix this?

```
public static void main (String Args[]){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swords & Sworcery");               
    frame.setSize(1920,1080);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(new OpeningSplash());

    final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel(); 
    frame.add(fxPanel); 
    initFX(fxPanel); 
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

    MUSIK.playIntro();

}
```

Comment: ``String Args[]`` O_o. You need to put ``frame.setVisible(true)`` on the last line.

Comment: Wait, but then wouldn't the frame stay invisible until the whole game is done? (the game will be put where playIntro is)

Comment: Also, what's wrong with String Args[]? I'm new

Comment: @user3138314 usually it is written `String args[]` or `String ...args`. i.e. `camel case` rather than `title case`

Comment: @user3138314: The only thing starting with capital letters in Java are classes, interfaces and enumerations... and constants in the early days, now lower case is preferred

Answer (score 2):

It is quite simple to understand. Think of all of your components as peripherals to your computer. You are essentially putting your computer ON before attaching all of the peripherals.

setVisible() completes the addition of all entities to your JFrame so that when you display, everything is intact.

Refer to ["Why to use setVisible() below our code!"](http://java-demos.blogspot.com/2013/11/why-should-we-write-setvisible-at-last.html)

So you should invoke your adding of components before setting the frame visible.

Hope this clears up things

Comment: Correct, or use repaint, invalidate or something like that.If you add components after setVisible.

Comment: Please mark correct if I assisted or pointed you in the right direction.